# C#: Are callback functions inside lock statement also locked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, thread-safety, locking

I have a function which deserialize an Xml document and create objects from it.

I want the objects to be stored into cache so i don't have to deserialize the xml every time i need to get data from it.

```
public class XMLDeserializer
{
    public event OnElementDeserialized OnElementDeserializedCallback;

    public void DeserializeXml(string xmlPath)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class XMLDeserializerFacade
{
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    private XMLDeserializer xmlDeserializer;
    private ICacheProvider cacheProvider;
    public XMLDeserializerFacade(XMLDeserializer xmlDeserializer, ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
        this.xmlDeserializer = xmlDeserializer;
        this.cacheProvider = cacheProvider;

        xmlDeserializer.OnElementDeserializedCallback += delegate(object element)
        {
            cacheProvider.Add("uniqueKey", element);
            // is here in lock as well or i have to lock it again?
        };
    }

    public void DeserializeXml(string xmlPath)
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            xmlDeserializer.DeserializeXml(xmlPath);

            // From here it will go to
            // cacheProvider.Add("uniqueKey", element);  callback
        }
    }
}
```

When i want to deserialize the xml, i call

```
XMLDeserializerFacade.DeserializeXml("file.xml")
```

My question is that i should use `lock` also inside the `OnElementDeserializedCallback` callback as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a lot on the specific implementation. If the code that invokes that is on the same thread as the main `lock` / `DeserializeXml`, and it uses the *synchronous* version (`OnElementDeserializedCallback(...)` or `OnElementDeserializedCallback.Invoke(...)`) - then it will already be inside the existing lock, because the lock is essentially tied to the thread.

If the implementation uses an *asynchronous* implementation (`BeginInvoke`, `Task`, `ThreadPool` etc), then no: it will *not* be inside the lock.

If unsure, you *could* lock in both places (since locks are re-entrant, it doesn't matter if you end up having nested locking twice from the same thread); however, if it turns out it *is* asynchronous, but it also then tries to *join back* to the callback (`Delegate.EndInvoke`, `Task.Wait`, etc) then it could totally deadlock.

Comment: I will double lock just to make sure it's locked :)